# ask-cli, Ask deploy, UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

**I am new to alexa and frustrated with below error :**

> UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the
>   request is invalid

I am able to create the new skill with ask new command for example :

AWS profile "ask_cli_default" was successfully associated with your ASK profile

but when i use ask deploy it gives above mentioned error.

Can anyone help ?
.

Comment: Did you also run ask init? Did you associate that account with default?

Answer (score 1):

After long hours of RnD i could solve this with below command :

> ask deploy -p **yourprofilename**

Hope it will help someone needed.